# Angular2 get number of dynamicly added li inside ul

Tags: angular

I want to get number of dynamicly added li inside ul. I need it to set width of queue element depending on number of li with [style.width.px]="numberOfLi * 50". How to make it work?

```
<ul class="queue">
    <li 
        class="queue__item"
        *ngFor="let images of actualModel.imgDir; let i = 'index + 1'"
        [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(' + actualModel.imgDir[i] + ')'}"
    ></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the array length for that, in your case `actualModel.imgDir.length`

```html
<ul class="queue" [style.width.px]="actualModel.imgDir.length * 50">
    <li 
        class="queue__item"
        *ngFor="let images of actualModel.imgDir; let i = index + 1; let x = length"
        [style.backgroundImage]="'url(' + actualModel.imgDir[i] + ')'"
    ></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Okay but I need to set that with to ul element, not li.